# Supply and Demand Graphs in R

Tags: r, econometrics, ggplot2, macroeconomics

Does anyone know of any R package that can make visuals for economics like the classic supply and demand graph? Obviously I googled this and found a package called "reconPlots" but I believe it's outdated and no longer functioning. Then I found [this blog post](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2017/09/15/create-supply-and-demand-economics-curves-with-ggplot2/), which had some really cool visuals but the code is very long and tedious and doesn't run right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists a package for just economical data visualizations. What kind of functionality do you need that the basic R graphics cannot offer you? The more you want to customize your graphs, the longer and more tedious the code comes in R, that is just the nature of it. I still think it is worth investing time to learn the basic R graphics or maybe ggplot if that is your thing. I myself rely these days on the basic R-graphics as it allows making simple and informative graphs with minimal effort.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVMFYowmAMg) is a You-Tube tutorial about data visualization for economics with ggplot.

[Here](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/smanzan/files/aedr/BUS4093unit3.pdf) A more throughout introduction for ggplot in economics.

[Here](https://blog.modeanalytics.com/r-data-visualization-packages/) is a blog post about different data visualization packages for R

And last, but not least [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-base-graphs) for basic R and some other options.

Comment: Thanks. I was just curious. I didn't need it for anything in particular. This is interesting though.